# What is the scope of Django's Middlewares?

Tags: django, sqlalchemy, middleware, django-middleware

What is the scope of Django's Middleware objects? I wish to know if the Middleware objects are initialized for every request.

**Relevance**: While trying to use SQLAlchemy ORM along with Django, one needs to point a callable object as the scope marker to use the SQLAlchemy's scoped_session. And I'm trying to set the SQLAlchemy session in request scope.

Comment: [The examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) show what is initialised once and what is called for each request/response.

Comment: @Alasdair, Thanks. I've been going through the docs umpteen times, but missed to notice the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! The middleware is triggered for every single request.
Please go through [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) to learn more about middlewares and how to write one and use it properly.

For your requirements you should be able to do what you want in `process_request` (Django < 1.10) or at the start of `__call__` (Django 1.10+)